# Is there a word for someone who inadvertently makes your point for you?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, phrase-usage

For example: If a person tells another person, "You're racist" and the other person responds, "No, I'm not racist. But I just don't like to see Black and White people dating because it's not right", then the other person responds back, "Thanks for making my point."

Comment: "Is there a word for X" is a bit vague. Do you want a noun or an adjective? (or maybe even a verb)

Comment: Not sure if there's really a good word for this. I think you'd be better of just using a sentence as a dialogue response or as a description. Along the lines of, "You just proved my point!", or "That's an argument against your stance", etc. You might have a blank spot in your text/hypothetical conversation that only accepts words, but sometimes its better to just reimagine the entire text/conversation to allow a different approach. That said, there could very well be a perfect word out there for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

How about **self-defeating**? From Lexico:

> **[self-defeating](https://www.lexico.com/definition/self-defeating)**: (of an action) preventing rather than achieving a desired result; futile.

The person in your example is making a **self-defeating** argument, thereby inadvertently making your point for you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for this:

**take the words out of someone's mouth**

> Say what someone else was about to say.

*"You can only mumble ‘You took the words out of my mouth… ‘quietly while the boss praises them."*

[Lexico]

Answer (score 0):

One phrase which could describe such a person is

***give (oneself) away***

> To reveal or make known—usually unintentionally—something about
> oneself, such as one's actions, intentions, ideas, guilt, etc.
>
> - Margaret had been embezzling money from the corporate account for
>   years, but she finally gave herself away when she claimed her
>   two-month trip to Paris as a business expense. ([freedictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+oneself+away)).

Aside: This may be beside the point, but I would also describe such a person as ***guilty***. If you are not guilty, you have nothing to give away.